# Navigator.getGamepads() doesn't return different instances of the same type of gamepad

Tags: javascript, gamepad-api

As the title says, I don't get 2 different gamepads for the same type of controller (yes, I can see them in the Control Panel `joy.cpl`)

i.e. using Windows I can see in `joy.cpl` the following list:

```
Controller (XBOX 360 for Windows)
Saitek Pro Flight X-56 Rhino Stick
Saitek Pro Flight X-56 Rhino Throttle
6B Controller
6B Controller
```

while in Chrome (v84) I only get this:

```js
Array.from(navigator.getGamepads()).map(g => g.id);
// [
//  "Xbox 360 Controller (XInput STANDARD GAMEPAD)"
//  "6B controller (Vendor: 0ca3 Product: 0024)"
//  "Saitek Pro Flight X-56 Rhino Throttle (Vendor: 0738 Product: a221)"
//  "Saitek Pro Flight X-56 Rhino Stick (Vendor: 0738 Product: 2221)"
// ]
```

I was trying to investigate how to differentiate them if there were the same type, but it comes that I don't even get them...

Any way to get the 2nd `6B Controller`?

**Edit**
After testing with a newer Chrome version, I can confirm that is working now... so probably was an issue in an older version and it's fixed :)

Comment: Do you see both in `gamepadconnected` if you disconnect and reconnect them?

Comment: Tried that too, and only one of them is detected... looks like because both have the same ID string, they are treated as the same one (?)

Answer (score 0):

I just did a quick test and plugged in two identical gamepads into my machine, and both were detected:

```
0: Gamepad {id: "Xbox 360 Controller (STANDARD GAMEPAD Vendor: 045e Product: 028e)", index: 0, connected: true, timestamp: 222286.67000000132, mapping: "standard", …}
1: Gamepad {id: "Xbox 360 Controller (STANDARD GAMEPAD Vendor: 045e Product: 028e)", index: 1, connected: true, timestamp: 245434.25500000012, mapping: "standard", …}
```

Have you tried waking both controllers up (by pressing a button) before calling `navigator.getGamepads()`?

Comment: yes, I tried that of course. May I ask your browser type and version? I should test again and see if it was fixed...

Comment: I was using `Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_1_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.41 Safari/537.36` on macOS.

Comment: Took me long time to test again but yes, I can confirm it was fixed. Now I can see more than one controller of the same type :3 `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.128 Safari/537.36`

Comment: Perfect then . Good we can close this.